# Installing Eclipse C/C++ Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: eclipse, c++

looking to download the Eclipse CDT (IDE for C/C++)
but seems its currently unavailable for Ubuntu 20.04 in the apt package manager

looked for snaps and flatpaks , could not find any solutions there (they have only the Java IDE)
thinking about downloading the 'tar.gz' file but afraid that there would be dependencies issues, and the uninstallion would be hard

any help on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu repositories are lagging behind on Eclipse I'm afraid. I always use the .tar.gz file. Simply unpack it, and run the `eclipse` binary.

You'll need Java installed on your system: `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre`. Other than Java, I don't think there are dependencies. And if there are, you will quickly run into them: Eclipse will not start. Just remove the directory of your unzipped Eclipse installation, and walk away